# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.21.144.1", user "smath", database "customer", no encryption

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I need your help please. I am new to spring boot and Iam learning from a course about microservices and spring cloud. I have a basic app and setting up a database on docker with postgres.

I'm trying to connect my spring boot app to my postgresql database running on docker and this is the error I get:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.21.144.1", user "smath", database "customer", no encryption
```

It's looks like an encryption error but i dont know how to solve this issue

Here is my applicaton.yml file

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    username: 'smath'
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/customer
    password: 'smath'
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
          format_sql: 'true'
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      show-sql: 'true'
```

and my pg_hba.conf file looks like this

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    customer        smath           172.21.144.1            md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

plus this is my docker-compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: smath
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: smath
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

I will appreciate your help

Comment: First: never use md5 for encryption, it is hopelessly out of date and trivially brute forced these days. Set that to `scram-sha-256` as well if you want actual security, or if your connection is already secured through SSL, then you can use `password`. And then of course second: if you're getting errors for code that's trying to connect, remember to also [show that code](/help/how-to-ask) (unless you get this error with really just these files of course, without actually running any of your own code yet, but then please mention that explicitly)

Comment: You cannot get that error with this `pg_hba.conf`. Either you are looking at the wrong file, or you didn't reload the server after you changed it.

Comment: What version of postgresql you are using?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I did reload it and yes I’m looking to the right file

Comment: @maddy23285 version 14

Comment: What happens if you try again after you do `docker exec -it -u postgres postgres "psql -c 'select pg_reload_conf()'"`? And what do you get from `docker exec -it -u postgres postgres "head /data/postgres/pg_hba.conf"`?

Comment: Check postegresql driver version in POM.xml. Change it to the latest version if you are using the old one. Add below lines in your POM.xml nested under dependencies tag. 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.5.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found a solution. It seems like it was a conflict between my local installed postgres and the docker one. I just stop the service of the local installed one and everything work fine. So thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I Found a solution. It was a conflict between my local installed postgres and the docker installed version. I just stop the service of the local one and everything work fine.